# Help porting c++ to php code

Tags: php, c++

I need if possible port this function to c++:

```
static unsigned char bux_code[3] = {0xFC, 0xCF, 0xAB};

void bux_convert(char* buf, int size)
{
        int n = 0;
        // ----
        for (n=0;n<size;n++)
        {
                buf[n]^=bux_code[n%3];
        }
}
```

What i have done:

```
$bux_code = array("\xFC", "\xCF", "\xAB");

function bux_convert($string)
{
    $size = strlen($string);

    for ($n = 0; $n < $size; $n++) {
        $string[$n] ^= $bux_code[$n % 3];
    }

    return $string;
}

var_dump ( bux_convert("£Ì•½Ï¼«ü") );
```

But i got this error: Cannot use assign-op operators with overloaded objects nor string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can't always address an offset of a string like `$mystring[5]` or `$mystring[$k]` and then treat the resulting character as a numeric value in every respect. Here's a way you could get around it: turn the string into an array at the start of `bux_convert()`, using `str_split()`, and then turn it back into a string at the end, using `implode()`.

Also, `$bux_code` is a global variable and won't be visible inside the function. Either move it inside the function or declare it as a global.

```
function bux_convert($string)
{
    $bux_code = array(0xFC, 0xCF, 0xAB);

    $size = strlen($string);
    $string = array_map('ord', str_split($string));

    for ($n = 0; $n < $size; $n++) {
        $string[$n] ^= $bux_code[$n % 3];
    }

    return implode('', array_map('chr', $string));
}

var_dump ( bux_convert("£Ì•½Ï¼«ü") );
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you (and all others)!

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 $bux_code = array(hexdec("FC"), hexdec("CF"), hexdec("AB"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is complaining about the "^=" assignment operator.

So, try doing what the error message suggests, and rewrite the assignment without using the assign-op operator:

```
$string[$n] = $string[$n] ^ $bux_code[$n % 3];
```

Comment: Ok, working now. But function returning "2212212212". In c++ it returning normal word

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly port globals to the function, so on the first line of your function put the line:

```
global $bux_code;
```

Now, the variable is not found, is undeclared, and therefor xor cannot operator on it.